# Case Feed Notification

Tags: chatter, case, feeditem

Hi i need to know whether we can remove "You're receiving emails when someone "Posts on one of my cases."

To change or turn off ****email, log in as" from case feed notification email.Below the attached screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off email from Chatter for all users by going to Setup>Build>Customise>Chatter>Email Settings and then untick the Allow Emails and/or Allow Email Replies.

[Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=collab_admin_email_settings.htm&siteLang=en_US)

[image]